# Synonym request [tabbarcontroller] for [uitabbarcontroller]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

[uitabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/uitabbarcontroller) is the tag for specialized iOS control.

But, we have the tags [uittabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/uittabbarcontroller) and [tabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/tabbarcontroller), both are referring [uitabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/uitabbarcontroller)

I can burninate [uittabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/uittabbarcontroller), since it has only 10 questions.

But, [tabbarcontroller](/questions/tagged/tabbarcontroller) has more than 150 questions. So, I'm suggesting the synonym request for it.

I can't vote for tag synonyms, as I don't have the required score on this tag :(

[image]